# Wifi not there in legion 5 pro 2021 while using ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, lenovo, realtek

Well, I recently bought a lenovo legion 5 pro (2021). The wifi is not there which i expected but I also expected a solution to exist which it does, but it does not work for me.

**Laptop Spec**

```
**Processor** 
    AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800H Processor (8 Cores / 16 Threads, 3.20 GHz, up to 4.40 GHz with Max Boost, 4 MB Cache L2 / 16 MB Cache L3)
```

```
**Display Type**
    40.64cms (16.0) WQXGA (2560x1600) IPS 500nits Anti-glare 165Hz 100% sRGB Dolby Vision HDR 400 Free-Sync G-Sync DC Dimmer
```

```
***Memory*** 
    16 GB SO-DIMM DDR4 3200MHz
```

```
**Graphics** 
    NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3060 6GB GDDR6
```

```
**Wireless**
    Wi-Fi 6, 802.11ax 2x2 Wi-Fi + Bluetooth® 5.1, M.2 Card
```

**Edit** I also found that my wifi adapter is MediaTek Wifi 6 mt7921.

**Edit**
For those who are wondering if the wifi adapter is appearing or not, when I go to ubuntu settings, there is no wifi option(No wifi icon). Which I think is due to the fact that wifi adapter is not recognized at all.
But It works perfectly fine in windows btw.

When I do `ip a`, this is what I get.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:2e:16:d4:a9:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 192.168.29.144/24 brd 192.168.29.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 2728sec preferred_lft 2728sec
    inet6 2405:201:3016:e09d:8488:89ba:27fe:78ca/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3578sec preferred_lft 3578sec
    inet6 2405:201:3016:e09d:c974:f445:e4ec:a3bd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3578sec preferred_lft 3578sec
    inet6 fe80::b42b:7ebc:1058:d55c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have no idea what to do, please help! And thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What happens when you just try to connect to WiFi normally (e.g., via the WiFi icon)? Is the icon not there at all? Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `ip a` as well?

Comment: I have edited the question, thank you for your response!!

Comment: You need a newer kernel for your adapter. And it is Mediatek. So Realtek drivers won't work.

Comment: I figured eventually, can I update kernel though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so updating the kernel seems to do the trick here.

What finally solved it for me was to install an OEM kernel. I believe either 20.04c (5.13) or 20.04d (5.14) is required since the Mediatek wireless card drivers require at least 5.12 to work. In my case, I installed 20.04d using

`sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04d`

WiFi+BT works.